# React: Component wont reload - even though new state has been set

Tags: reactjs

I have the following problem: I've written a 'detailview' component, that takes a PK from a list and uses it to fetch the right object from the API. As this takes some time it will display 'Loading' by default.

My render looks like this:

```
render() {

        if (!this.store_item) {
            return <h2>loading</h2>
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.store_item.results.title}</h2>
                <p>{this.state.store_item.results.description}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The 'store_item' is loaded when the component mounts:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.LoadApi();
}
```

The 'LoadApi' method has the following code:

```
LoadApi() {
        const new_url = encodeURI(this.state.store_item_api + this.props.detail_pk);
        fetch(new_url, {
            credentials: 'include',
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result =>
                this.setState({
                    store_item: result,
                }));
    }
```

However, when I run this code in my browser all I see is 'Loading'. Yet when I check the state in the chromium react extension I can see that 'store_item' has been set (I also verified that the api call went as planned in the network tab).  As the state has been set (and is being set in 'LoadApi') my understanding was that this should trigger an re-render.

Does anyone know why, despite all this, the component keeps returning 'loading'?

Comment: The easiest thing to do when debugging state or prop changes is to do `console.log(this)` before your return statement inside `render()`. That usually gives me a good clue on where to look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typo, missed *`state`* keyword

```
if (!this.store_item) { ... }
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Should be

`if (!this.state.store_item) { ... }`

Because it's defined as component state instead of component static property.

Comment: Ah, such a stupid mistake. It seems I need more coffee. Thanks for the assist!